# Simple Java 2d array maze sample

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, depth-first-search, maze

I am working or understanding how to create a simple ***java 2d maze*** that should look like this:

```
int [][] maze = 
{ {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

};
```

Ones this has been created the idea is to set a starting point and goal point and by using recursive depth first find the path. but must say i am having difficulties to create the maze.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do it?
Or perhaps a link to a tutorial?
The main focus for me right now is just to create the maze.

Comment: @pedromss to be honest not much since i have tried to find a tutorial on how to, but they all seems to be rather complicated and none are done for dummies

Comment: or explain why is going on step by step, its easy to copy paste a code, but wont get much from that, nor understanding. and thats not the goal for me

Comment: "Create a maze" is an awfully broad question. A "maze" does not have a clear mathematical definition, I think. You'll need to be more specific. If any maze-like structure is fine, I'm sure you can whip up something very simple, which still would allow you to test the solving algorithm.

Comment: If you have a basic understanding of arrays and loops in java and also  look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html I think you'll manage to get there on your own. If you feel like you're lost maybe you need to read up on programming basics. Good luck

Comment: So what you want to do first is put wall tiles on the places of the 1 and free floor tiles at the places of 0? Or just clear the screen and put circles or boxes at the positions of the 1? You can study on (zetcode.com) the java2d and java2d games tutorials for simple and not so simple first examples.

Comment: @Santelices Was my answer useful for your research?

Comment: if the ones (1) represent your maze's wall I hope you are outside!!

Comment: if you don't want to see all boilperate code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592057/simple-implementation-of-a-maze-generation-method-random-dfs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maze implementation has a lot of variations.

All depends on which of there aspects you want to use?

Here is some start point [Maze generation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm).

I tried to solve this problem in the past. Instead of many words how I tried this, I guess to show code snippet.

maze generator **code**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyMaze {
  private int dimensionX, dimensionY; // dimension of maze
  private int gridDimensionX, gridDimensionY; // dimension of output grid
  private char[][] grid; // output grid
  private Cell[][] cells; // 2d array of Cells
  private Random random = new Random(); // The random object

  // initialize with x and y the same
  public MyMaze(int aDimension) {
      // Initialize
      this(aDimension, aDimension);
  }
  // constructor
  public MyMaze(int xDimension, int yDimension) {
      dimensionX = xDimension;
      dimensionY = yDimension;
      gridDimensionX = xDimension * 4 + 1;
      gridDimensionY = yDimension * 2 + 1;
      grid = new char[gridDimensionX][gridDimensionY];
      init();
      generateMaze();
  }

  private void init() {
      // create cells
      cells = new Cell[dimensionX][dimensionY];
      for (int x = 0; x < dimensionX; x++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < dimensionY; y++) {
              cells[x][y] = new Cell(x, y, false); // create cell (see Cell constructor)
          }
      }
  }

  // inner class to represent a cell
  private class Cell {
    int x, y; // coordinates
    // cells this cell is connected to
    ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
    // solver: if already used
    boolean visited = false;
    // solver: the Cell before this one in the path
    Cell parent = null;
    // solver: if used in last attempt to solve path
    boolean inPath = false;
    // solver: distance travelled this far
    double travelled;
    // solver: projected distance to end
    double projectedDist;
    // impassable cell
    boolean wall = true;
    // if true, has yet to be used in generation
    boolean open = true;
    // construct Cell at x, y
    Cell(int x, int y) {
        this(x, y, true);
    }
    // construct Cell at x, y and with whether it isWall
    Cell(int x, int y, boolean isWall) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.wall = isWall;
    }
    // add a neighbor to this cell, and this cell as a neighbor to the other
    void addNeighbor(Cell other) {
        if (!this.neighbors.contains(other)) { // avoid duplicates
            this.neighbors.add(other);
        }
        if (!other.neighbors.contains(this)) { // avoid duplicates
            other.neighbors.add(this);
        }
    }
    // used in updateGrid()
    boolean isCellBelowNeighbor() {
        return this.neighbors.contains(new Cell(this.x, this.y + 1));
    }
    // used in updateGrid()
    boolean isCellRightNeighbor() {
        return this.neighbors.contains(new Cell(this.x + 1, this.y));
    }
    // useful Cell representation
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Cell(%s, %s)", x, y);
    }
    // useful Cell equivalence
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Cell)) return false;
        Cell otherCell = (Cell) other;
        return (this.x == otherCell.x && this.y == otherCell.y);
    }
    // should be overridden with equals
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // random hash code method designed to be usually unique
        return this.x + this.y * 256;
    }
  }
  // generate from upper left (In computing the y increases down often)
  private void generateMaze() {
      generateMaze(0, 0);
  }
  // generate the maze from coordinates x, y
  private void generateMaze(int x, int y) {
      generateMaze(getCell(x, y)); // generate from Cell
  }
  private void generateMaze(Cell startAt) {
      // don't generate from cell not there
      if (startAt == null) return;
      startAt.open = false; // indicate cell closed for generation
      ArrayList<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();
      cells.add(startAt);

      while (!cells.isEmpty()) {
          Cell cell;
          // this is to reduce but not completely eliminate the number
          //   of long twisting halls with short easy to detect branches
          //   which results in easy mazes
          if (random.nextInt(10)==0)
              cell = cells.remove(random.nextInt(cells.size()));
          else cell = cells.remove(cells.size() - 1);
          // for collection
          ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
          // cells that could potentially be neighbors
          Cell[] potentialNeighbors = new Cell[]{
              getCell(cell.x + 1, cell.y),
              getCell(cell.x, cell.y + 1),
              getCell(cell.x - 1, cell.y),
              getCell(cell.x, cell.y - 1)
          };
          for (Cell other : potentialNeighbors) {
              // skip if outside, is a wall or is not opened
              if (other==null || other.wall || !other.open) continue;
              neighbors.add(other);
          }
          if (neighbors.isEmpty()) continue;
          // get random cell
          Cell selected = neighbors.get(random.nextInt(neighbors.size()));
          // add as neighbor
          selected.open = false; // indicate cell closed for generation
          cell.addNeighbor(selected);
          cells.add(cell);
          cells.add(selected);
      }
  }
  // used to get a Cell at x, y; returns null out of bounds
  public Cell getCell(int x, int y) {
      try {
          return cells[x][y];
      } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { // catch out of bounds
          return null;
      }
  }

  public void solve() {
      // default solve top left to bottom right
      this.solve(0, 0, dimensionX - 1, dimensionY -1);
  }
  // solve the maze starting from the start state (A-star algorithm)
  public void solve(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
      // re initialize cells for path finding
      for (Cell[] cellrow : this.cells) {
          for (Cell cell : cellrow) {
              cell.parent = null;
              cell.visited = false;
              cell.inPath = false;
              cell.travelled = 0;
              cell.projectedDist = -1;
          }
      }
      // cells still being considered
      ArrayList<Cell> openCells = new ArrayList<>();
      // cell being considered
      Cell endCell = getCell(endX, endY);
      if (endCell == null) return; // quit if end out of bounds
      { // anonymous block to delete start, because not used later
          Cell start = getCell(startX, startY);
          if (start == null) return; // quit if start out of bounds
          start.projectedDist = getProjectedDistance(start, 0, endCell);
          start.visited = true;
          openCells.add(start);
      }
      boolean solving = true;
      while (solving) {
          if (openCells.isEmpty()) return; // quit, no path
          // sort openCells according to least projected distance
          Collections.sort(openCells, new Comparator<Cell>(){
              @Override
              public int compare(Cell cell1, Cell cell2) {
                  double diff = cell1.projectedDist - cell2.projectedDist;
                  if (diff > 0) return 1;
                  else if (diff < 0) return -1;
                  else return 0;
              }
          });
          Cell current = openCells.remove(0); // pop cell least projectedDist
          if (current == endCell) break; // at end
          for (Cell neighbor : current.neighbors) {
              double projDist = getProjectedDistance(neighbor,
                      current.travelled + 1, endCell);
              if (!neighbor.visited || // not visited yet
                      projDist < neighbor.projectedDist) { // better path
                  neighbor.parent = current;
                  neighbor.visited = true;
                  neighbor.projectedDist = projDist;
                  neighbor.travelled = current.travelled + 1;
                  if (!openCells.contains(neighbor))
                      openCells.add(neighbor);
              }
          }
      }
      // create path from end to beginning
      Cell backtracking = endCell;
      backtracking.inPath = true;
      while (backtracking.parent != null) {
          backtracking = backtracking.parent;
          backtracking.inPath = true;
      }
  }
  // get the projected distance
  // (A star algorithm consistent)
  public double getProjectedDistance(Cell current, double travelled, Cell end) {
      return travelled + Math.abs(current.x - end.x) + 
              Math.abs(current.y - current.x);
  }

  // draw the maze
  public void updateGrid() {
      char backChar = ' ', wallChar = 'X', cellChar = ' ', pathChar = '*';
      // fill background
      for (int x = 0; x < gridDimensionX; x ++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < gridDimensionY; y ++) {
              grid[x][y] = backChar;
          }
      }
      // build walls
      for (int x = 0; x < gridDimensionX; x ++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < gridDimensionY; y ++) {
              if (x % 4 == 0 || y % 2 == 0)
                  grid[x][y] = wallChar;
          }
      }
      // make meaningful representation
      for (int x = 0; x < dimensionX; x++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < dimensionY; y++) {
              Cell current = getCell(x, y);
              int gridX = x * 4 + 2, gridY = y * 2 + 1;
              if (current.inPath) {
                  grid[gridX][gridY] = pathChar;
                  if (current.isCellBelowNeighbor())
                      if (getCell(x, y + 1).inPath) {
                          grid[gridX][gridY + 1] = pathChar;
                          grid[gridX + 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                          grid[gridX - 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                      } else {
                          grid[gridX][gridY + 1] = cellChar;
                          grid[gridX + 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                          grid[gridX - 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                      }
                  if (current.isCellRightNeighbor())
                      if (getCell(x + 1, y).inPath) {
                          grid[gridX + 2][gridY] = pathChar;
                          grid[gridX + 1][gridY] = pathChar;
                          grid[gridX + 3][gridY] = pathChar;
                      } else {
                          grid[gridX + 2][gridY] = cellChar;
                          grid[gridX + 1][gridY] = cellChar;
                          grid[gridX + 3][gridY] = cellChar;
                      }
              } else {
                  grid[gridX][gridY] = cellChar;
                  if (current.isCellBelowNeighbor()) {
                      grid[gridX][gridY + 1] = cellChar;
                      grid[gridX + 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                      grid[gridX - 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                  }
                  if (current.isCellRightNeighbor()) {
                      grid[gridX + 2][gridY] = cellChar;
                      grid[gridX + 1][gridY] = cellChar;
                      grid[gridX + 3][gridY] = cellChar;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

  // simply prints the map
  public void draw() {
      System.out.print(this);
  }
  // forms a meaningful representation
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      updateGrid();
      String output = "";
      for (int y = 0; y < gridDimensionY; y++) {
          for (int x = 0; x < gridDimensionX; x++) {
              output += grid[x][y];
          }
          output += "\n";
      }
      return output;
  }

  // run it
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyMaze maze = new MyMaze(20);
      maze.solve();
      maze.draw();
  }
}
```

It isn't the best solution, my task at this time was implement this algorithm by myself. It has clear comments.

***Output:***

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X * X ********* X ***** X   X       X
X * X * XXXXX * X * X * X   X   X   X
X ***** X ***** X * X * X   X   X   X
XXXXXXXXX * XXXXX * X * X   X   X   X
X       X ***** X * X * X       X   X
X   X   XXXXX * X * X * XXXXXXXXX   X
X   X       X ***** X *             X
X   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX * XXXXXXXXXXXXX
X ***************** X ***** X       X
X * XXXXXXXXXXXXX * XXXXX * X   X   X
X ***** X       X ********* X   X   X
XXXXX * X   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X
X ***** X         ***** X     ***** X
X * XXXXXXXXXXXXX * X * XXXXX * X * X
X ************* X * X * X ***** X * X
XXXXXXXXXXXXX * X * X * X * XXXXX * X
X             ***** X ***** X     * X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I hope it will be useful as an illustration of some solution.

Comment: This looks like very useful code, but I'm having trouble reconciling the difference between dimensionX and gridDimensionX (and Y).  When I define a grid of, say 10, the picture that comes back is bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably completely outdated, but...

First, you should realize that the underlying structure of such a maze is an undirected graph on a 2-dimensional grid. Now to create a so called "perfect maze", you just have to create any spanning tree of a full grid graph. And to do that there are plenty of algorithms, from random graph traversals (BFS, DFS) over algorithms derived from the known minimum-spanning tree algorithms (Kruskal, Prim, Boruvka, Reverse-Delete) to algorithms creating "uniformly random" spanning trees (Wilson, Aldous-Broder) to other algorithms that don't fit into these categories like "recursive division", "Eller's" etc.

I implemented lots of these algorithms based on a grid graph structure and you can find my implementation here:

https://github.com/armin-reichert/mazes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone problem ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what I would do is:
1. create a board of a specific size (change all the coordinates to your desired number - in your example '1').
I wouldn't use a recursive function, because you will probably end up drawing the whole board (think about what will make the recursion stop).

you can create a function that receives a starting coordination, an ending coordination,
and the array (the board).
pseudo code of the function:
set a variable for the next direction of painting (set it to the starting coordination).
paint the next coordination 0.
while the next coordination != to the ending coordination:
paint the next coordination 0.
use Random to set the coordination to one of the 4 directions.

you should add limits (if the next coordination is a painted one/the border of the maze etc... chose a different coordination).
good luck!