# How can I make an algorithm that will randomly put 1's in a 2d array while making sure there's a path from the bottom left to the top right space?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, random, maze

I am trying to make a simple java game where the player cannot see the world (a 2d array) and has to enter "right," "left," "up," or "down." The player has to get from the bottom left to the top right in a certain time. The array will be full of 0's and 1's will be assigned randomly, while making sure there's a path between the start and end.
This is what I have so far:

```
public class PathMaker {

    private int [][]arr;

    public PathMaker(int Difficulty){
        if (Difficulty == 1)
            arr = new int[5][5];
        if (Difficulty == 2)
            arr = new int[5][5];
        if (Difficulty == 3)
            arr = new int[5][5];
        Pathset(arr);
    }

    private static void Pathset(int [][]arr){
        int length = arr.length;
        int trees = (length-1)*2;
        int a, b;
        int check = 0;
        arr[0][0] = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < trees; i++){
            a = (int)((Math.random()*length)+1);
            b = (int)((Math.random()*length)+1);
            while(check == 0){
                if (((arr[a+1][b] == 0) && (arr[a][b+1] == 0)) || a == 1 || b == 1)
                    check = 1;
                a = (int)((Math.random()*length)+1);
                b = (int)((Math.random()*length)+1);
            }
            arr[a][b] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner, so please explain to me exactly how to do it, thank you.

Comment: you might want to check out this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Java 2d array maze sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815839/simple-java-2d-array-maze-sample)

Comment: Choose a path first.  Then choose obstacles for squares that aren't on the path.

Comment: Try to make it "tree structured", when you start at your generation at the entry point and then generate each next randomly chosing from the neighbors of previous. Then you may add some more random cells and you should have your field with existing path and other random braches!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want a result that looks like randomly scattered trees instead of a maze, but ensuring that there will be a path through.

There will be a path to the bottom-left square to the top-right square as long as there is no chain of trees connecting the top or left side to the bottom or right side.

You can solve this using a union-find data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

1. Make a set for the top+left sides and a set for the bottom+right sides.  During the algorithm you'll also add sets for all the trees you add.
2. Iterate through the squares in random order, and try to add a tree for each one, as follows.
3. To test a square, find all the sets it connects to. That includes the top-left set and/or bottom-right set if it's on a wall, and all the sets for trees in adjacent squares.  If both the top-left and bottom-right sets are included, then you can't add a tree in that square, so go to the next one.
4. If the square passes, then add a tree. Make a new set for the tree and merge it with all the sets it connects to that you found in (3).
5. Stop when you have enough trees.